# Not getting field name in invalid value error message on Data annotation for list of dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, modelstate

I have a MVC application with similar code. I add the date fields on click of a button using JS.

Model:

```
public class FruitViewModel
{ 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<FruitDate> DateList {get;set;}
}

public class FruitDate
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime BuyDate{get;set;}
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime SellDate{get;set};        
}
```

My View :

```
<input asp-for="Id" type="hidden">
<button id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add row" class="btn btn-default">Save Changes</button>
<button id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default">Save Changes</button>
<div id="divFruits" class="row">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function (e) {
    let newDiv = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> +
                 '<div class="col-xs-6"><input class="form-control" type="date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The BuyDate field is required." id="DateList_0__BuyDate" name="DateList[0].BuyDate" value="' + currentdate + '"> </div>' +
                 '<div class="col-xs-6"><input class="form-control" type="date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SellDate field is required." id="DateList_0__SellDate " name="DateList[0].SellDate " value="' + currentdate + '"></div>' +           
                 '</div ></div >'

 $('#divFruits').append(newDiv);
});
```

The button click adds a new row in divFruits and all of this works fine.

On submit, it goes to the controller and the code is as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveFruits(FruitViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }
         var allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(b => b.ErrorMessage));
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "An error occured. Please try again");
    }
}
```

It is working fine all the time and the Buy and Sell Dates are being binded to the model. On an invalid buy or sell date, say 02/31/3019 the model state fails as expected. However the allErrors variable has message

> The value '' is invalid.

Why am I not getting the name of the field which is the invalid field, something like The value 'FruitDate[0].BuyDate' is invalid.

Comment: `name="FruitDate[0].SellDate` or `name="DateList[0].SellDate` ?

Comment: @NaDeRStar Thanks for pointing out the mistake. The error persists.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the name of the field because `DataType` attribute doesn't validate before binding from post data to model.

To make your `Required` attribute works, you have to change your `DateTime` fields nullable:

```
public DateTime? BuyDate{get;set;}

public DateTime? SellDate{get;set};
```

Comment: I do not need the Required attribute. I need to know which field has a bad date.